# Writing a comparator function for specific type within template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm working with a library which has a template class and it stores a `std::vector` of all the template type passed to it.

I pass `std::tuple<A, B, C*>` to that template class (where A, B, C are classes I've implemented).

I want to add an additional line to that class in which I'll call `std::sort` on that `std::vector`. Is there any way to pass/implement a comparator operator to `std::sort` which works for that specific type?

First I thought of writing `operator<` for A, B, C but quickly realised that the third tuple parameter I pass is a pointer to C. And since pointer is not a user-defined type, I won't be able to overwrite the default operator.

I also, read about `typename` but I'm not clear with it's use and don't know if it is applicable here. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some additional code? What you want is plausible, but with relevant code, you're likely to get a more helpful answer. As an aside, the `typename` keyword is used in a template declaration (e.g. `template < typename T >`) , or as a way to disambiguate a [qualified dependent type](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html#dependent) (e.g. `template < typename T > class X { typename T::iterator itr; };`).

Comment: @txtechhelp I avoided the original code because it's very complicated and will make the question hard to read. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are dealing with a standard type it is not so nice to specialize a comparator for that type. It's more simple to define a custom comparator and [use it](https://ideone.com/1wIWF8) when needed, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using tuple_t = std::tuple<int, float, int*>;

int main() 
{
    auto comparator = [](const tuple_t& t1, const tuple_t& t2) 
    {
      if (std::get<0>(t1) == std::get<0>(t2))
        return *std::get<2>(t1) < *std::get<2>(t2);
      else
        return std::get<0>(t1) < std::get<0>(t2);
    };

    std::vector<tuple_t> data;
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), comparator);
}
```

If you really find yourself calling `std::sort` a lot of times, or you want to provide the type with the required operator then maybe it's better to define a custom type instead that using `std::tuple`.

Comment: Actually, the vector is declared as a private variable of that class, so I won't be able to access it outside. I like your second suggestion, I guess if I find no decent way, I'll implement a custom type.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add your own templated `MyComparator<T>` class, that would default to `std::less<T>` in all the cases except `std::tuple<A,B,C*>`:

```
template<typename T> struct MyComparator : public std::less<T>
{};

template<> struct MyComparator<std::tuple<A,B,C*>>
{
    // your own operator() here
};
```

And then just use that comprator in the `std::sort` inside of your template:

```
std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), MyComparator<T>{});
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Just one more question, I should add this code to the library class, right?

Comment: So technically the specialised comparator will be used whenever the specific type is passed, right?

Comment: @LaschetJain yes, I thought you can tweak the library code since you were planning to add the `std::sort` call to it anyway.  

The specialized comparator will be used if the type matches, so you need to be a bit careful if you have e.g. `std::tuple<A,B,D*>` where `D` is derived from `C`, but otherwise I think it's your best option

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out tomorrow and if it works, I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: You can also only add the generic version of the comparator to the library code, and the `MyComparator<std::tuple<A,B,C*>>` specialization to wherever your library template is instantiated. That way the library itself will stay unaware of `A`,`B`,`C` classes.